# Problem in Dual-Boot can't find window boot

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, windows-10

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with the intention of dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu. My C: drive is a 240GB SSD with not enough free space for Ubuntu so I partitioned D: and added a 250GB partition and told it to install Ubuntu.

After doing that I rebooted my PC and a new boot menu comes up with several choices.  Windows boot was not one of them so I figured I screwed up and overwrote my C: drive boot tracks.

After much panic and screaming I bought a new 480 GB SSD and replaced my old C: drive with it. I then rebooted my PC and it boots up UBUNTU!

My old C: drive is on my bench so obviously it was booting from the D: drive where I actually did install it.  I then removed my D: drive and reinstalled my old C: drive and it booted up windows with everything intact.

My problem is that with both C: and D: installed it doesn't give me the option to pick which operating system I want to use.  Only Ubuntu.  That should be and easy thing to fix but I have no idea where to start.

This is my first attempt to use Ubuntu.  Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem once, and it was because of my BIOS. See, if you start you computer and access the BIOs you might see an option to change between Legacy Support and UEFI mode, these are kind of BIOs. What happend in my case is that i had windows in UEFI and Ubuntu on Legact, and since i had my bios as legacy it booted ubuntu by default and was impossible to access windows. You should try to reboot your computer and open the OS select screen (in some PCs is done by holding down ESC, others with F2 and others with F9, it changes) and see if you can choose windows (with your C: and D: drives installed).

If that is not the case you might need to update your Grub, but i cant know for sure, can you post some pictures of you boot up procces?
BTW, this should be posted as a comment, but i dont have enough reputation yet, so, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

OOPS!  I goofed.  I forgot to take out the thumb drive with the Linux iso file and it was booting from that.  I didn't do any damage to my windows files.  I've decided to run Ubuntu from a virtual PC/drive. Lesson learned, I/m going to make a recovery disk now.  Thanks to everyone that replied.
Art